# opencv manager package was not found?? how install automatcally?

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

I am working on openCV, and whenever i run code it gives me package manager is not installed, So how can i installed this through my application.Is it compulsory to download it from play store or we can installed it automatically in device. please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use static initialization to include all OpenCV binaries in the apk.
Please refer this documentation: [Application Development with Static Initialization](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization)

Comment: I am facing same problem. Hows you resolved.Please help me.Thanks in advance..

Comment: In the documentation they wrote "Static initialization is deprecated for the production code"

Comment: You won't get that if you use JavaCV: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/

Answer (score 5):

1- after you download Opencv library from this site:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/

2- open apk folder, there are some opencv manager package.

3- select one that suitable for your device and install it.

Important Note: if the package (the apk file) you select is not suitable for your device you will get `opencv library package was not found`.

Comment: Small tip, I did this directly on main mobile with a unzip app and installed the apk

Answer (score 3):

you can also run :

```
adb install OpenCV_***_Manager_***.apk
```

from the shell locally

Comment: it will run on emulator, but whenever installed in android different devices then how will i handle it.

Comment: this also works with the real device connected. but it may still be a bad answer, as you have to figure out manually , which apk to install, also you need adb/naked_Driver (which your clients probably won't have)

Comment: yes, this is not a good answer, if i upload it on playstore than how can we do this thing, this is the main problem.

Comment: @MuhammadAhsanMaqsoodAwan Were you able to find the solution for this? Am also facing the same problem.

Comment: I got.. `monolaebseus-MacBook-Pro:~ monolabs$ adb install OpenCV_***_Manager_***.apk
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to stat OpenCV_***_Manager_***.apk: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

You did not copy the contents of libs folder which is inside the native folder

After downloading and unzipping the OpenCv release and after importing the module in the android studio project (by File > New > Import Modules and choosing the java folder inside the unzipped sdk) you also have to go to.

Opencv-android-sdk > sdk > native > libs

and copy the entire the contents

Then go to your android project and inside the app folder you have to make a new folder by the name of **jniLibs** and copy the contents there followed by a Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me and will shall work for you.

1. Unzip and Copy the "OpenCV-android-sdk" project in the root of your android project.

Example:

```
root
  -Project
  -OpenCV-android-sdk
```

2. Open settings.gradle of your project and paste the code according to your project

   ````
    def opencvsdk = '../OpenCV-android-sdk'
    include ':<opencv- project-name>'
    project(':<opencv- project-name>').projectDir = new File(opencvsdk + '/sdk')```
   ````

Now Sync and run the project.